# Stream read error

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm getting this error message under heavy load. Here is code abstract and message from my error log.
I tried everything I could think of. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

```
Procedure tCacheInMemory.StreamValue(Name: String; IgnoreCase: Boolean; Var Stream:     TStringStream);
Var
  i: Integer;
Begin
  i := 0;
  Try
    If Not active Then
      exit;
    arrayLock.BeginRead;
    Try
      i := Search(Name);
      If i > -1 Then Begin
        If fItems[i].value = Nil Then
          exit;
        fItems[i].value.Position := 0;
        Stream.Position := 0;
        Stream.CopyFrom(fItems[i].value, fItems[i].value.Size);
      End;
    Finally
      arrayLock.EndRead;
    End;
  Except { ...execution jumps to here }
    On E: Exception Do Begin
      x.xLogError('LogErrorCacheInMemory.txt', 'StreamValue:' + E.Message + ' ItemsCount:' + IntToStr( High(fItems)) + 'Memory:' + IntToStr(x.GetMemoryInfoMemory) + endLn + 'StreamSize : ' + IntToStr(fItems[i].value.Size) + ' i=' + IntToStr(i) + 'Name: ' + Name);
      Clear;
    End
  End;
End;
```

Log Entries:

```
 3/10/2011 10:52:59 AM: StreamValue:Stream read error ItemsCount:7562 Memory:240816
   StreamSize : 43 i=7506 Name: \\xxxxxxxx\WebRoot\\images\1x1.gif
3/10/2011 12:39:14 PM: StreamValue:Stream read error ItemsCount:10172 Memory:345808
   StreamSize : 849 i=10108 Name: \\xxxxxxxx\WebRoot\\css\screen.add.css
3/10/2011 3:45:29 PM: StreamValue:Stream read error ItemsCount:11200 Memory:425464
   StreamSize : 3743 i=11198 Name: \\xxxxxxxx\WebRoot\\JS\ArtWeb.js
```

P.S.

```
arrayLock: TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer;
 fItems: Array Of rCache;
Type
  rCache = Record
    Name: String;
    value: TStringStream;
    expired: TDateTime;
  End;
```

And calling function:

```
Function tCacheInMemory.CacheCheck(cName: String; Out BlobStream: TStringStream):   Boolean;
Begin
Result := False;
   If Not IfUseCache Then
      exit;
    BlobStream.SetSize(0);
    BlobStream.Size := 0;
    StreamValue(trim(cName), True, BlobStream);
    If BlobStream.Size > 0 Then
    Result := True;
End;
```

`

Comment: Are you sure that "Stream" is created?   I see no code checking for that.    You do it for the Items[].Value.   Also what does Search() Do? Does it interact with the streams?

Comment: You marked where execution jumps *to* - where does it jump *from* to get there?

Comment: Stream is created. You can see in error log StreamSize and size in bytes. Items.Value is a TStringStream. Search is a customized binary search. It doesn't interact.Only returns index.

Comment: StreamSize in your log refers to Items[].value not the Stream variable.   You have multiple stream variables in your code.

Comment: Two things about your code unrelated to the error: (1) You shouldn't pass the `Stream` parameter as `var`. Pass it by value, and change its declared type to just `TStream`, allowing callers to pass any type of stream instead of exactly `TStringStream` objects. (2) If the stream you find in the cache is *shorter* than the destination stream's current contents, then the destination stream will contain garbage at the end. You need to truncate it after copying.

Comment: To @robert-love Items[].value is a Stream variable. To @rob-kennedy point 1 taken. Destination Stream being created just before calling cache so it's always empty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not using correct locking. You're acquiring a *read* lock on the array of cache entries, but once you find the item you want, you *modify* it. First, you *explicitly* modify it by assigning its `Position` property, and then you *implicitly* modify it by reading from it, which modifies its `Position` property again. When other code attempts to read from that same cache item, you'll have interference. If the source stream's `Position` property changes between the time the destination stream calculates how many bytes are available and the time it actually requests to read those bytes, you'll get a stream-read error.

I have a couple pieces of advice related to this:

- Don't use streams as a storage device in the first place. You're apparently holding the contents of files. You're not going to change those, so you don't need a data structure designed for making sequential changes. Instead, just store the data in simple arrays of bytes: `TBytes`. (Also, use of `TStringStream` in particular introduces confusion over whether those strings' encodings are important. A simple file cache shouldn't be concerned with string encodings at all. If you *must* use a stream, use a content-agnostic class like `TMemoryStream`.)
- Don't quell an exception that you haven't actually handled. In this code, you're catching *all* exception types, logging some information, clearing the cache, and then *proceeding as though everything is normal*. But you haven't done anything to resolve the problem that triggered the exception, so everything is *not* normal. Since you're not really handling the exception, you need to make sure it propagates to the caller. Call `raise` after to call `Clear`. (And when you log the exception, make sure you log the exception's `ClassName` value as well as its message.)

Comment: Thanx Rob. You saved my day. `TBytes` sounds promising. Regarding error handling - it's by design. If something bad happens result would be an empty string which will trigger refresh of this resource from other source (file,database etc.). I shouldn't call `Clear` and will not (after I'll fix it). I'll log `Class Name` as you advised. Thank you again. Yuriy.

Comment: You're handling EReadError, EAccessViolation, EOutOfMemory, and EPrinterOnFire as though they're all equal and can all be solved with a simple log message. What, specifically, are you expecting to catch? Nothing is ever supposed to go wrong in that code, so if something *does* go wrong, you need to know about it immediately because there's a bug in your program. If a program error is indistinguishable from an ordinary cache miss, then instead of reading a stack trace that points to the exact error, you'll instead collect reports of subtle data-corruption.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It looks like something external is blocking your stream files.</strike>

You could try to use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see what blocks it.

Another thing you can try is to open the stream in read-deny-write mode (please show us how you open the stream).

Something like this:

```
Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite) ;
```

*Edit 1:* Disregard the strike through part: you are using TStringStream.
I'll keep the answer just in case anyone ever gets this kind of error when using TFileStream.

*Edit 2:* [Yuriy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661437/yuriy) posted this interesting addendum, but I'm not sure it will work, as the `BlobStream` is not initialized, just like [Robert Love](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93161/robert-love) suspected:

```
Function TCacheInMemory.CacheCheck(cName: String; Out BlobStream: TStringStream): Boolean; 
Begin 
  Result := False; 
  Try 
    If Not IfUseCache Then 
      exit; 
    BlobStream.SetSize(0);  
    BlobStream.Size := 0;  
    StreamValue(trim(cName), True, BlobStream);  
    If BlobStream.Size > 0 Then  
      Result := True;  
  Except  
    On E: Exception Do  
    Begin  
      x.xLogError('LogErrorCacheInMemory.txt', 'CheckCacheOutStream:' + E.Message + ' ItemsCount:' + IntToStr( High(fItems)) + 'Memory:' + IntToStr(x.GetMemoryInfoMemory));  
    End;  
  End;  
End;
```

--jeroen

Comment: @jeroen Don't worry, you'll get your 2 points back once you delete it!

Comment: @David: ah, so deletes work like that. Good to know, but I'd rather keep this piece of knowledge here, just in case someone else can benefit from it.

Comment: @Yuri: you should make that part of your question; in the mean time I will add it to my answer (and credit you for it), if you add it to your question, I will remove it from my answer.

Comment: @Jeroen Why did you add this code to your answer? Surely it belongs in the question?

Comment: @David to give Yuriy the chance to update his question. It gives him the chance to get some experience here (he is a new user).